# Python: convert website scraped data from row into column from inside nested loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, xlsxwriter

I am trying to convert row into column which is generated in nested for loop.

In a nutshell it is like this:
Value1 is in row and data that belongs to value 1 has to be as column
Value2 is in row and data that belongs to value 2 has to be as column

How it is right now is
All of the Values are exported as rows and after that all of the Values for a value is exportes as row which is making it unreadable.

The thing is to get Value1, value2 etc... I have to go through for loop and to get all of the data for value 1 I need to go through another for loop (nested loop).

All of the data I am taking is from a website(scraping).
I have included imgurl link to how it is and how it should be(my progress so far). First one is how it is and second one how it should be. I believe with a image it is easier to explain than with my own words.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/eS3R4.jpg

I am using pandas and xlsxwriter for storing to excel. 
I managed to export all of the data to excel I need but I can't seem to convert values for each value as column. 
First line is time. This is working how it should be.

```
        #Initialize things before loop
        df = pd.DataFrame()
        ### Time based on hour 00:00, 01:00 etc...
        df_time = pd.DataFrame(columns=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23])

        for listing in soup.find_all('tr'):

            listing.attrs = {}
            #assetTime = listing.find_all("td", {"class": "locked"})
            assetCell = listing.find_all("td", {"class": "assetCell"})
            assetValue = listing.find_all("td", {"class": "assetValue"})


            for data in assetCell:

                array = [data.get_text()]
                df = df.append(pd.DataFrame({
                                        'Fridge name': array,
                                        }))

                for value in assetValue:

                    asset_array = [value.get_text()]
                    df_time = df_time.append(pd.DataFrame({
                                                'Temperature': asset_array
                                                }))
                ### End of assetValue loop
            ### End of assetCell loop

        ### Now we need to save the data to excel
        ### Create a Pandas Excel writer using XlsxWriter as the Engine
        writer = pd.ExcelWriter(filename+'.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')

        ### Convert dataframes
        frames = [df, df_time]
        result = pd.concat(frames)

        ### Convert the dataframe to an XlsxWriter Excel object and skip first row for custom header
        result.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='SheetName', startrow=1, header=True)

        ### Get the xlsxwritert workbook and worksheet objects
        workbook = writer.book
        worksheet = writer.sheets['SheetName']

        ### Write the column headers with the defined add_format
        for col_num, value in enumerate(result.columns.values):
            worksheet.write(0, col_num +1, value)

            ### Close Pandas Excel writer and output the Excel file
            writer.save()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of testing I went with another approach. Instead of messing with pandas I went with **tabulate** to scrape the whole data and then export the whole table structure as csv.

```
from tabulate import tabulate
import csv
import datetime ### Import date function to make the files based on date
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup



 if (DAY_INTEGER <= 31) and (DAY_INTEGER > 0):

    while True:
        try:
            ### Validate the user input
            form_data = {'UserName': USERNAME, 'Password': PASSWORD}
            with requests.Session() as sesh:
                sesh.post(login_post_url, data=form_data)
                response = sesh.get(internal_url)
                html = response.text
                break
        except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
            print ("Whoops! This is embarrasing :( ")
            print ("Unable to connect to the address. Looks like the website is down.")

    if(sesh):

        #BeautifulSoup version
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'lxml')
        table = soup.find_all("table")[3] # Skip the first two tables as there isn't something useful there
        df = pd.read_html(str(table))


        df2 = (tabulate(df[0], headers='keys', tablefmt='psql', showindex=False))

        myFile = open(filename+'.csv', 'w')
        myFile.write(str(df2))

    else:
        print("Oops. Something went wrong :(")
        print("It looks like authentication failed")
```